# What deities/creatures personify the universe in the aspect that it manifests as varied duplexity (that serve the same symbolic function as Yin/Yang)?

Tags: mythical-creatures, myth-identification, symbolism

I'm looking for deities or mythological creatures that symbolize the universe in the aspect that it manifests as a duality (which is for example symbolized by the Yin/Yang), but as a fictional organism/spirit rather than a plain symbol, an example would be [Eliphas Levi's Baphomet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baphomet) who is an organism of united polar opposites (female/male, man/beast, angel/demon, good/evil).

Do any deities or creatures like that exist apart from Baphomet?

Comment: Hello. The image was a bit large, and I think it was unnecessarily stealing focus from the question. Feel free to put it back in if you feel it's essential to the question, but please consider using a smaller version if you do.

Comment: @yannis I agree, it was too large.

Comment: ShivShakti and Ardhanaeshwara from Hinduism?

Comment: It's a very long list.  When I get a chance I'll post a few.  (Great question, btw.)  At a high level, a very fine scholar of the classics once related to me that the entirety of Greek Mythology could be understood from the perspective of the "unification of opposites."  This is a common theme in paganism which tends to be preoccupied with generative cycles. These cycles, for the most part, require the unification of the opposite sexes.  The I-Ching was the first formalization of this idea in binary code, but the principle is pretty universal.

Comment: @DukeZhou Nice summation, have you formed your list yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dionysus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionysus) is a great place to start—Baphomet is almost surely based, in part, on this figure.

- Dionysus is sometimes depicted as the "horned god", encompassing the human/animal binary.
- Dionysus the "Dying/Resurrected God", representing the life/death binary.
- Dionysus is depicted with feminine attributes (long hair, "eastern" grooming which was considered feminized to the Greeks) suggesting the male/female binary.

Regarding gender, it's notable that gender reversal were part of the [Dionysian Mysteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionysian_Mysteries), appearing in such forms as transvestism and the female maenads taking on masculine attributes such as strength, ferocity, and freedom to roam.  [The Bacchae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bacchae) of Euripides is a very important source work. *(At its core, the play is a commemoration of the dismemberment and his subsequent resurrection of the god, but even the Wikipedia summary provides a good sense of binaries dealt with in the play, primarily the tension between intellect and instinct, but also the dual nature of Dionysus himself.)*

---

[Persephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persephone) is, in some sense, the female counterpart to Dionysus. She represents grain (body), where he represents wine (spirit).

- Persephone is both Maiden and Crone
- Persephone symbolizes both growing and dying ("Summer"/"Winter")
- She has two names, Kore ("[Girl](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ko%2Frh&la=greek&can=ko%2Frh0#lexicon)") and Persephone ("Destroyer")

[Graves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Graves) translates "Persephone" as "Bringer of Destruction": ["πέρσε"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=*perse&la=greek#lexicon) + ["φονή"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=fo%2Fnh&la=greek#Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=fona/w-contents), although the second word, with an omega for the omicron, ["φωνή"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=fwnh%2F&la=greek&can=fwnh%2F0&prior=fwn-e/w) relates to sound, thus Persephone can also be understood as "She who robs (people) of their voice" (i.e. death) and by extension, life, as voice requires breath, and breath is literally spirit in *[psuke](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=yuxh&la=greek#lexicon)*, *[pneuma](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=pneuma&la=greek#lexicon)*,   and the root of the Latin *["anima"](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=anemos&la=greek#lexicon)*

Persephone is sometimes considered the mother of the [primal form of Dionysus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zagreus), and/or the nymph [Melinoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melinoe), however, the sources are cloudy, originating from the "mysteries", and can be considered corollary. Even so, the binary of infertile/fertile can be represented by possible status as mother.

---

[Eros](http://www.theoi.com/Ouranios/Eros.html) is also certainly in this category, being thought of, alternately, as both the oldest and youngest of the gods. In the philosophical conception of Aristotle, [drawing on Hesiod](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0052%3Abook%3D1%3Asection%3D984b), Eros the principle (love, desire) is said to be quite specifically the "[origin](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=a%29rxh%2F&la=greek&can=a%29rxh%2F0)" of "[all things that exist](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=ou%29%3Dsin&la=greek&can=ou%29%3Dsin1&prior=toi=s&d=Perseus:text:1999.01.0051:book=1:section=984b&i=2)".  Thus Eros embodies a binary (oldest/youngest) and presides over the unification of opposites (generation through unification of the sexes).  Hesiod was drawing on ideas that would now be understood as [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics#History).

---

These deities are understood to be [liminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liminal_being), although the current Wikipedia entry on [liminal deities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liminal_deity) is quite limited in scope, being concerned only with deities who *literally* preside over thresholds, as opposed to deities who actually embody oppositional qualities which *form* the thresholds they straddle.

---

[Loki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki) is a distinctly liminal figure:

- Loki is sometimes [Asgardian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asgard) and also part [jötunn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6tunn).
- Loki is both benefactor and nemesis.
- Loki can become female

Loki tricks the giant who builds the walls of Asgard, and becomes female to bear Sleipnir (*[Gylfaginning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki#Gylfaginning)*), but he also is responsible for the death of Baldur, and is the central agent of [Ragnarök](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnar%C3%B6k) which is a transition.

Loki is "bright" in the sense of cleverness, but also "dark" in the sense of spite.  (It's probably not random that his punishment involves venom, and it's also possible that his name partly derives from the [Indo-European root for light](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/luk-).)

---

Those are my favorites, but embodiment of such binaries can be seen in:

- [Janus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janus)

Two faces. Represents past/future, as well as other transitions.

- [Ganesha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesha)

Part animal, part human.  Remover or placer of obstacles (facilitating or obstructing transitions). Literally a guardian of thresholds in that, in some version, he stood guard by [his mother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parvati)'s door and refused to allow [Shiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva) entry.

- The [Green Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Man)

Both vegetable and human.  Intersection of the mind and nature. Crowley's "The Fool" [See below] references the Green Man, who is very specifically *straddling* the body of the image, which may be interpreted as the phenomenal world, and also incorporates horns and a distinctly animalistic visage.

- [John Barleycorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Barleycorn)

Dionysus variant.

- The [Christ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucifixion)

Both god and man.  Gateway to salvation.  The cross, or "[crux](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=crux)" is a literal representation of intersection.

---

These are just a few, famous examples, but the concept of [liminality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liminality) is central to all such figures.

[image]

Comment: Super job! Thanks. Pleasing to see the Christ included. A mythology often neglected because its adherents tend to "hate" the suggestion that it _is_ mythology. Perhaps, as both angel and demon, bringer of light and source of darkness, Lucifer belongs on the list as well?

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Lucifer is a great example.  (It's not a subject where I have much academic knowledge, but you should think about posting an answer, since Lucifer, like Dionysus, certainly influenced Lievi's Baphomet.)   I have a personal hypothesis that Loki strongly influenced Lucifer--Loki was the adversary, but also beloved for being clever and interesting (Paradise Lost).  Loki was very close with the Sky Father before transgressing and being cast out.  Like the Morningstar, he is the agent of an apocalypse.

Comment: What little this student has to add fits well in a comment, and your comment draws even more parallels than I saw, even knowing the material behind them. Any answer I could give would only detract from, not enhance, the information you've given.

Comment: What's that last image of / for?

Comment: @Mithrandir The Fool card from the [Thoth tarot deck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoth_tarot_deck).  *(Most information dense tarot out there, thanks in no small part to the artwork of Lady Frieda Harris.)*